# How can I change the way java.awt.Graphics draws my object?

Tags: java, graphics, awt, draw

I'm creating a game and have a class for Player, class for Enemy, and class for Bullet. With the design of my engine, it is most logical to draw my graphics by simply calling 
    `for (Shape s : shapes
    {
g.fill(s)
}`
where `shapes` is an already existing `List<Shapes>` of every object in my game. This works just fine, however I would like the bullet to be colored differently from the player, and the player from the enemies. How can I modify my Player, Bullet, and Enemy classes so that awt.Graphics knows which color to draw them as?

Edit: Another acceptable answer could maybe involve finding a way to sort through `shapes` and separate it by class, although that seems counter intuitive with the complete list already existing.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

[image: Colored Shapes]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

class ColoredShapes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));

                final ArrayList<Drawable> drawables = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
                final PaintPanel paintPanel = new PaintPanel(drawables);
                gui.add(paintPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                final Random r = new Random();

                JToolBar tools = new JToolBar();
                gui.add(tools, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

                JButton addCircle = new JButton("Add Circle");
                ActionListener addCircleListener = new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        Point p = new Point(r.nextInt(400), r.nextInt(400));
                        int s = r.nextInt(50) + 50;
                        Color c = new Color(
                                r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255));
                        drawables.add(new DrawableCircle(p, s, c));
                        paintPanel.repaint();
                    }
                };
                tools.add(addCircle);
                addCircle.addActionListener(addCircleListener);

                JButton addSquare = new JButton("Add Square");
                ActionListener addSquareListener = new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        Point p = new Point(r.nextInt(400), r.nextInt(400));
                        int s = r.nextInt(50) + 50;
                        Color c = new Color(
                                r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255), r.nextInt(255));
                        drawables.add(new DrawableSquare(p, s, c));
                        paintPanel.repaint();
                    }
                };
                tools.add(addSquare);
                addSquare.addActionListener(addSquareListener);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

interface Drawable {

    public abstract void draw(Graphics2D g);

    public abstract Color getColor();
}

class DrawableCircle implements Drawable {

    private Color color;
    private Shape shape;

    DrawableCircle(Point topLeft, int size, Color color) {
        shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(topLeft.x, topLeft.y, size, size);
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setColor(getColor());
        g.fill(shape);
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}

class DrawableSquare implements Drawable {

    private Color color;
    private Shape shape;

    DrawableSquare(Point topLeft, int size, Color color) {
        shape = new Rectangle2D.Double(topLeft.x, topLeft.y, size, size);
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setColor(getColor());
        g.fill(shape);
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}

class PaintPanel extends JPanel {

    Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension(400,400);
    ArrayList<Drawable> drawables;

    PaintPanel(ArrayList<Drawable> drawables) {
        this.drawables = drawables;
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return preferredSize;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, 
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        for (Drawable drawable : drawables) {
            drawable.draw(g2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer  I'm considering entering it into a competition  for 'Cubist art'.  I guess the circles won't help..  ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use OOP
example

```
 Interface Shapes{
  public Color getColor() ;
 }
 class Player implements Shapes{ 
     public Color getColor() {
        return Color.red;
     }
 }
 class Enemy implements Shapes{ 
     public Color getColor() {
        return Color.green;
     }
 }
 //  now the Paint

 for (Shape s : shapes} { g.fill(s.getColor())};
```

Comment: there is no such method `g.fill(Color)`. Pls check

Comment: I don't understand how this would work. g.fill(Shape) does not take a Color as an argument so g.fill(s.getColor()) would be like trying to say g.fill(Color.green) would it not? That wouldn't work

Comment: I gave you the concept. The other things like what method to use to fill the colore etc. you can search for that 
see the link for all methods used for graphics
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the color differentiation, then call `g.setColor(Color)` before calling `g.fill(s)`

Comment: You didn't understand, I have a list of a lot of shapes, some should be colored differently than others

Comment: This answer makes perfect sense.  So it seems it is you who does not understand.  As to how to determine the correct color to set, you might follow the general advice in the other answer (though I suspect that last line will not compile) or check for `instanceof` to determine the `Color`..

Comment: Yes, I can combine these two answers to make it work, thanks, but neither of them REALLY answer my original question, which is "how can I make it so that g.fill KNOWS what color I want a class to be?"

Comment: @BrianC. it is your own logic, that you have to implement. You cannot make `g.fill()` know by itself... `g.fill()` will only fill the shape with some color that was set using `g.setColor(Color)`

Comment: I would extend the advice of @aymankoo to include a `draw(Graphics g)` method.  There it would a) set the color for that object b) draw it.  That way, in the main app. you'd simply iterate the collection and call the draw method of each, supplying the `Graphics` object.

Comment: @BrianC. Shape is a concept. It does not carry any color or pant information.  You need to tell the Graphics context what color or paint you want to use

Answer (score 1):

You could associate each Shape with a Color using a Map of some kind.  Then when your painting each shape, you would simply need to dos something like...

```
for (Shape shape : shapes) {
    Color color = mapColors.get(shape)(
    if (color != null) {
        g.setColor(color);
    } else{
        // set the color to a default value 
    }
    g.fill(shape);
}
```

The problem with this approach, for me, is it disassociates the shape from the color. It also limits the way on which an asset can be painted

A better solution would be to devise a `Asset` class the provides a simple `paint` method.  To would allow each asset to define the way in which it wants to be rendered

```
public interface Asset {
    public void paint(Graphics g);
}
```

You would then simply use a `List` of assets, similar to you shape list, but call `paint(g)` (on the instance of the `Asset`) instead, allowing the asset to decide how it should be painted...